# Error on entering insert mode in gvim

Tags: vim, ubuntu

When I enter the *insert* mode in gvim while editing a `.py` file, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>99_on_insert_enter:
line    7:
E490: No fold found
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

It's extremely irritating, since i have to press esc and go into insert mode again, or press enter. How do I find which script causes this error?

Comment: Yes, drop SPF13. There's probably an `autocmd` somewhere that is triggered on `InsertEnter`. Since you chose the "easy" way and gave someone else control over your configuration you'll have to go look for it through your plugins and multiple `vimrc`s and figure out what to do with it.

Comment: Giving control of my editor to a community-driven configuration helps me in multiple ways - I have the best of plugins, I get my environment wherever I go, and I can ask doubts here. And that suggestion - I don't need. If you have answers, come up with them.

Comment: I can install my own environment wherever I go as well. You have someone's favorite plugins, not "the best plugins". And it's freaking hard to answer janus/spf13 questions because everything is put in non-standard places or there are too many plugins/options to take into account. Because I control my own environment I don't get surprises like this one: I install and configure what I want, how I want it. Now, did you look around for `autocmd`s or mappings that would lead you to that situation as I suggested? Try `:verbose autocmd` and `:verbose map`.

Comment: Well, i have my own reasons for going for spf13. I have to change OSs frequently, so I have to go into setting up the whole environment very often. So What i do instead, is download spf13, comment out some plugins, install the rest. Now, all I wanted was how to know which script caused it - If I hadn't mentioned spf13, I would have got the answers easier i guess. Thanks for the 'constructive' suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:scriptnames` and watch out for the line starting with `99:`; it tells you which script contains the problematic line. Then, depending on the script and your level of Vim knowledge, you can try to find and fix the problem, or just disable the offending plugin it belongs to.